# MySQL query runs ok in phpMyAdmin but hangs in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, cpu-usage, freeze

I have a fairly simple query which runs okay when I test it in phpMyAdmin:

```sql
   SELECT   
        c.customers_id,
        c.customers_cid,
        c.customers_gender,
        c.customers_firstname,
        c.customers_lastname,
        c.customers_email_address,
        c.customers_telephone,
        c.customers_date_added,
        ab.entry_company,
        ab.entry_street_address,
        ab.entry_postcode, 
        ab.entry_city,
        COUNT(o.customers_id) AS orders_number,
        SUM(ot.value) AS totalvalue, 
        mb.bonus_points
   FROM     
        orders AS o,
        orders_total AS ot,
        customers AS c, 
        address_book AS ab, 
        module_bonus AS mb
   WHERE 
        c.customers_id = o.customers_id 
        AND c.customers_default_address_id = ab.address_book_id 
        AND c.customers_id = mb.customers_id    
        AND o.orders_id = ot.orders_id 
        AND ot.class = 'ot_subtotal'    
 **  AND c.customers_gender  = 'm' AND c.customers_lastname LIKE 'Famlex'
    GROUP BY o.customers_id
```

The row marked with ** changes depending on filtering settings of the application making the query.

Now, when I test this in phpMyAdmin, the query takes a couple of seconds to run (which is fine, since there are thousands of entries and, as far as I know, when using COUNTs and SUMs indexes don't help) and the results are perfect, but when I run the exact same query in PHP (echoed before running), the MySQL thread loads a core to 100% and doesn't stop until I kill it.

If I strip the extra stuff to calculate the COUNT and SUM, the query finishes but the results are useless to me.

EXPLAIN:

```
1   SIMPLE  mb  ALL     NULL                        NULL        NULL        NULL                                48713       Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  ot  ALL     idx_orders_total_orders_id  NULL        NULL        NULL                                811725      Using where
1   SIMPLE  o   eq_ref  PRIMARY                     PRIMARY     4           db.ot.orders_id                     1           Using where
1   SIMPLE  c   eq_ref  PRIMARY                     PRIMARY     4           db.o.customers_id                   1           Using where
1   SIMPLE  ab  eq_ref  PRIMARY                     PRIMARY     4           db.c.customers_default_address_id   1
```

EXPLAIN after applying indexes and using joins:

```
1   SIMPLE  c   ref     PRIMARY,search_str_idx              search_str_idx          98      const                                   1       Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  mb  ALL     NULL                                NULL                    NULL    NULL                                    48713   Using where
1   SIMPLE  ab  eq_ref  PRIMARY                             PRIMARY                 4       db.c.customers_default_address_id       1    
1   SIMPLE  ot  ref     idx_orders_total_orders_id,class    class                   98      const                                   157004  Using where
1   SIMPLE  o   eq_ref  PRIMARY                             PRIMARY                 4       db.ot.orders_id                         1       Using where
```

Comment: what does `explain select...` says for the above query, update the question add those details in there.

Comment: EXPLAIN added, although I don't know what any of that means.

Comment: Looks like we were making the same edits at the same time, @t.niese.

Comment: will be back in 50 minutes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use explicit join instead of implicit

```
SELECT  
c.customers_id,
c.customers_cid,
c.customers_gender,
c.customers_firstname,
c.customers_lastname,
c.customers_email_address,
c.customers_telephone,
c.customers_date_added,
ab.entry_company,
ab.entry_street_address,
ab.entry_postcode, 
ab.entry_city,
COUNT(o.customers_id) AS orders_number,
SUM(ot.value) AS totalvalue, 
mb.bonus_points
FROM    
orders o 
join orders_total ot on o.orders_id = ot.orders_id 
join customers c on c.customers_id = o.customers_id 
join address_book ab on c.customers_default_address_id = ab.address_book_id 
join module_bonus mb on c.customers_id = mb.customers_id 
where
ot.class = 'ot_subtotal'
c.customers_gender  = 'm' 
AND c.customers_lastname = 'Famlex'
GROUP BY o.customers_id
```

Assuming all the joining keys are also primary key of those tables viz:

```
o.orders_id, c.customers_id, ab.address_book_id
```

You will need to add the following indexes if they are not added already

```
alter table  orders add index customers_id_idx(customers_id);
alter table module_bonus add index customers_id_idx(customers_id);
alter table orders_total add index orders_id_idx(orders_id);
alter table orders_total add index orders_class_idx(class);
alter table customers add index search_str_idx(customers_gender,customers_lastname);
```

Make sure to take a backup of the tables before applying indexes.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer! The behaviour of the query is still the same, however. Still runs fine in phpadmin and hangs the process when used in php.

Comment: What does explain select says after the indexing is applied ? Since from the initial explain plan its scanning a massive number of rows.

Comment: Query goes through! It's slow as a turtle, but it works now. I will try and index every column we're going to search through.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share SQL dump of your record so that I can take a look ?

phpMyAdmin automatically adds limit clause to the **select** queries, that is why I think you are getting the impression that in phpMyAdmin query is running fine but not via you PHP script.
Try to add explicit limit clause to the query say limit 0, 1000 in phpMyAdmin before running and see if that makes performance of phpMyAdmin slower.

Comment: The number of results was always below 10 (as intended), even in complete queries, so that couldn't have been the issue. The issue was the lack of indexes on key columns it seems.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not responsible for performance optimization. If the query is causing performance roadblock, then it will be cause in both phpMyAdmin as well as in your custom PHP file.

Comment: Both of them executes mysql_query($sql) at the end